# Implementation of Distributed-Counter-Extension for local emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

The firebase extension for a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-counter) can be directly installed for the cloud and works just fine. To develop new features for an app I need to do this on the emulator to not interrupt the running server.

As the firebase extensions simply are cloud Functions[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823723/11003497), I thought about implementing the cloud function in my emulator by getting the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-counter/functions/lib) from the extension itself. This worked fine for other extentions so far...

#### Error and Disfunction when implementing

When implementing the javaScript version that i get the following error:

`function ignored because the unknown emulator does not exist or is not running.`

This problem can be fixed by rewriting the export line of the `index.js`functions, but is wont provide the expected functionality of the extension anyhow:

```js
exports.worker = functions.handler.firestore.document.onWrite(async (change, context) => {...});
```

to

```js
exports.worker = functions.firestore.document("").onWrite(async (change, context) => {...});
```

#### Question

Am i missing some implementaion or is an emulator missing? How can i implement this firestore extention?

There are **some similar questions**, but dont really talk about the implementation of the whole extension:

- [Applying a Distributed Counter to Cloud Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015842/applying-a-distributed-counter-to-cloud-code)
- [firebase distributed counter extension in cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473176/firebase-distributed-counter-extension-in-cloud-functions)

Comment: just fyi that Emulator support for Extensions is actively being worked on :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Update: The Firebase Emulator Suite now supports emulating extensions! To emulate this extension, first you'll need [to add it to your extension manifest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/manifest). The easiest way to do this is, from your local firebase directory, to run:

```
firebase ext:install firebase/firestore-counter
```

Then, next time you start up the emulators, the code for the extension will be downloaded and emulated.

One thing to note is that the Distributed counter extension uses a scheduled function. The emulator suite doesn't trigger these for you, so you'll have to trigger them yourself by sending a PubSub message to the PubSub emulator. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759093/how-to-invoke-firebase-schedule-functions-locally-using-pubsub-emulator/65759654#65759654) does a good job explaining how to do this